# How to mock a method that accepts no arguments and its supposed to work normally in 1 test, and supposed to throw an error in another test

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to get 100% coverage on my AWS project but I don't know how to mock methods that don't accept arguments AND are supposed to pass a test that makes them work properly(return values) and another test that makes them throw an error. I can't change the tech I am using so please try to help me with the things I am using right now.

I am using Nodejs, Typescript, Mocha, Chai, nyc and mock-require for mocking.

It's an AWS project so I am working with AWS methods

Here is the function and method, I am mocking describeAutoScalingGroups()

```js
    export async function suspendASGroups() {
    const autoscaling = new AWS.AutoScaling();

    const asgGroups = await autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups().promise();

    if (!asgGroups.AutoScalingGroups) {
        throw new Error("describeAutoScalingGroups inside of suspendAGSGroups didn't return any groups");
    }
    // some other stuff below
```

This is the TEST that is supposed to fail(Above this there is a test of the same function which will return regular values)

```js
it('Should throw an error, should fail', async () => {

        assertNative.rejects(awsFunctions.resumeAGSGroups());


        try {
            let result = await awsFunctions.suspendASGroups();
        } catch (e) {
            assert.isTrue(
                e.name == 'Error' &&
                    e.message == "describeAutoScalingGroups inside of suspendAGSGroups didn't return any groups",
                'describeAutoScalingGroups in suspendAGSGroups didnt have the proper error message'
            );
        }
    });
```

And here is the mock code

```js
public describeAutoScalingGroups() {
        const data = (): AWS.AutoScaling.Types.AutoScalingGroupsType => {


            return {
                // some values here
        };

        return {
            promise: data
        };
    }
```

I expect to be able to pass both tests, the one that expects a regular value and one that expects it to throw an error

here is a picture of the coverage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SThAx.png

I expect that red part to be gone :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your mock you need to return something for `AutoScalingGroupsType` that evaluates to false, since you have this check:

```
if (!asgGroups.AutoScalingGroups) { ... }
```

So you could simply do this:

```
public describeAutoScalingGroups() { 
    return {
        promise: () => {
            return { AutoScalingGroups: false }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was given an answer on reddit so I will post it here too:

You need a different mock for each test. You should setup your mocks in before/beforeEach hooks which you will get from mocha https://mochajs.org/#hooks.

Using sinon would make the mock creation cleaner but if you are stuck with mock-require then it looks like you will need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require#mockrerequirepath
--- end of comment

How I did it:

I made another mock file that is the same as the regular mock file, except this one can only fail functions(which is good)
Here is the code in the TEST:

```
describe('Testing FAILING suspendAGSGroups', () => {
    it('Should throw an error, should fail', async () => {

        const mock = require('mock-require');
        mock.stopAll();

        let test = require('./test/mocks/indexFailMocks');

        mock.reRequire('./test/mocks/indexFailMocks');

        let awsFailing = mock.reRequire('./handler');
        // the line above is pretty important, without it It wouldnt have worked, you need to reRequire something even if it's the code of it isn't changed(I only changed the MOCK file but I had to reRequire my main function)

        try {
            let result = await awsFailing.suspendASGroups();
        } catch (e) {

            assert.isTrue(
                e.name == 'Error' &&
                    e.message == "describeAutoScalingGroups inside of 
suspendAGSGroups didn't return any groups",
                'describeAutoScalingGroups in suspendAGSGroups didnt have the proper 
error message'
            );
        }
    });
});
```